# undefined method `assign_attributes' for [13]:Array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

My app is set up that when product.sold attribute is 1 means an item is sold and it wont show up in the store views. I am trying to get it so when the customer checks out the product.sold attribute is updated when the item is purchased.

Here is the line of code in my controller that should be updating the product.sold attribute from nil to 1:

```
class ChargesController < ApplicationController
def create
      @order.order_items.map{ |o| o.product.id }.assign_attributes(sold: 1)
end
```

here are my associations:

```
OrderItem belongs_to :product
 OrderItem belongs_to :order
 Product has_many :order_items
 Order has_many :order_items
```

here is the error I am getting when I try to purchase a product with an id of 13

```
NoMethodError in ChargesController#create
undefined method `assign_attributes' for [13]:Array

Extracted source (around line #12):

       #OrderMailer.order_email(@order).deliver_now
       @order.update_attribute(:order_status_id, 2)
       @order.order_items.map{ |o| o.product.id }.assign_attributes(sold: 1)

       @final_amount = @amount
```

I have also tried update_attributes and update in place of assign_attributes. Not sure what else to try. Let me know if more info is needed.

Comment: So do you want to set an attribute on each item in the order?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to call `assign_attributes` on array of products IDs, but not models. Try this:

```
def create
    product_ids = @order.order_items.map{ |o| o.product.id }
    Product.where(id: product_ids).update_all(sold: 1)
end
```