# NoMethodError: undefined method `assign_attributes' for #<Message:0x00>

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

We are facing a sporadic issue in one of our message processing service. We got the following error

```
NoMethodError: undefined method `assign_attributes' for #<Message:0x00>
```

Here `Message` is an active record class. Given the same input to the service, it works successfully most of the times and fails a few times with this error.

The error happens while creating a new record.

```
Message.create(data: '', status: '')
```

Any thoughts would be helpful? Thanks.

Comment: did you check this https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/AttributeAssignment/assign_attributes

Comment: also if is array in game https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41308917/undefined-method-assign-attributes-for-13array

Comment: @Nezir Thanks. I checked them. But they do match to this question.

Answer (score 0):

The process was reading messages from an input queue. The issue was because we had the queue listener in the rails initializer.

Due to this when the service was started with messages in the input queue, it instantly started processing the messages. But the rails booting hasn't been completed yet due to some heavy usage in the cluster we were using. So it turns out to be a timing issue. For now we have added some sleep to give time for the rails to be ready.

We are planning to eventually move the queue listener out into a background job.